# React Native: react-native-camera-kit onRead returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I used the same code as given in their Readme to test this. I'm

```
 <CameraKitCameraScreen                            
           showFrame={true}
           scanBarcode={true}
           laserColor={"blue"}
           frameColor={"yellow"}          
           onReadCode={((event) => console.warn('Qr code found',event.nativeEvent.codeStringValue))} 
           hideControls={false} 
           isShowFrameForScanner={true}     
           colorForScannerFrame = {'blue'} 
         />
```

The Barcode is read. But the 'event' argument is undefined. I tried to contact the mod there, no response.

Environment

- React Native version: 0.54.0 Platform(s)
- Android Device info : Redmi Note 4, Android Version 7.0 NRD90M, Debugging mode

Comment: Hi, which `react-native-camera-kit` version do you use?

Comment: Can you try to `console.log` (or `warn`) the `event.nativeEvent`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not using it anymore. I'm using another one instead and it's working smoothly https://github.com/sahir/react-native-barcode-reader

Comment: Sorry to hear :(